# what is the default value in logrotate.conf

Tags: logrotate

In `/etc/logrotate.conf`
is user permission different between Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04 releases?

```
#use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
#of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog
```

or

```
#use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
#of /var/log/syslog.
su  root adm
```

Comment: The question is totally unclear. There is no `logrotate.config` file, there is `/etc/logrotate.conf`. So what is the question? What version of Ubuntu toy are asking about?

Comment: i edited it ..... and my question is about the configuration or options included in it..... in some version it's like that # use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog
but i found it in other version
# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm 
is that normal ??

Comment: What are "some" versions that you mention? Where did you find `logrotate.config`?

Comment: in ubuntu 18 it's su root syslog .... in ubuntu 20.04 it's su root adm

Comment: So you have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 the permissions in `/etc/logrotate.conf` are

```
su root syslog
```

In 20.04 it is

```
su root adm
```

You've noticed it yourself.

Comment: i want to make sure about it .... second point why it is different ?

Comment: I have no idea why. It is either an upstream change of the `logrotate` package, or an Ubuntu change.

Comment: It is an Ubuntu change. This user asked the same question in Server Fault and I [answered it there](https://serverfault.com/a/1083548/153188).

Comment: yes ... thank you